# Destination host unreachable and gateway 0.0.0.0 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but couldnt get a wired internet connection.The desktop runs Ubuntu only and has not been set up for a wireless connection. To troubleshoot, I've used examples from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353825 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346164 to edit my  `/etc/network/interfaces` file but still couldn't go online. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

#### System info

```
$ more /etc/network/interfaces   
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 eth
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [1028:06c7]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7000000-f7020000 

enp0s31f6:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c  
          inet addr:169.254.7.129  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7000000-f7020000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1662035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1662035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:123743544 (123.7 MB)  TX bytes:123743544 (123.7 MB)
```

#### Gateway is 0.0.0.0

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6

$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 enp0s31f6
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp0s31f6
```

#### ping returns "Destination Host Unreachable"

```
$ ping 169.254.7.0
PING 169.254.7.0 (169.254.7.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.7.129 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.7.129 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.7.129 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

#### Edit

```
$ sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup -v enp0s31f6
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
Configuring interface enp0s31f6=enp0s31f6 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant

/sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.enp0s31f6.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp0s31f6.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.enp0s31f6.leases enp0s31f6  
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/d8:9e:f3:14:7d:5c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x97131a3b)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x97131a3b)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Gateway address 0.0.0.0 (even if it were possible) is unreachable. Target address 169.254.7.0 does probably not exist. And your address is a 169.254.x.y, which is a zeroconf [self-assigned link-local](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/) address, so there seems to be no DHCP server in your network..

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup -v enp0s31f6` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ridgy: I'm trying to get a connection by editing the interface file based on solutions that I've seen in the forum threads linked.@chili555: Thanks! I've edited my post to include the terminal output for the command.

Comment: As i supposed: Your network is configured for DHCP, but there seems to be no DHCP server in your local network, or it is not configured to offer you an IP address. Your dhclient sends DHCPDISCOVER a few times but does not get DHCPOFFER; therefore falls back to a self-assigned local link address (APIPA, see e.g. http://www.omnisecu.com/tcpip/dhcp-dynamic-host-configuration-protocol-messages.php). So please make sure there is a) a router/gateway in your network, and b) a correct configured DHCP server. Otherwise you won't have a chance to connect to the internet.

Comment: @ridgy: Thanks for the explanation. Turns out my internet port was dead, problem solved once it got reactivated.